# Python: numpy.genfromtxt - Need column names that contain invalid characters

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I am working on importing CSV files with `numpy.genfromtxt`.

The data to be imported has a header of column names, and some of those column names contain characters that `genfromtxt` considers invalid. Specifically, some of the names contain "#" and " ". The input data cannot be changed as it is generated by other sources that I do not control.

Using `names=True` and `comments=None`, I am unable to bring in all of the column names that I need.

I've tried overriding `numpy.lib.NameValidator.deletechars=None`, but this does not affect the NameValidator class instance that is actually in use.

I understand that `deletechars` exists due to the recarray potential to access a field as if it were an attribute. However, I simply must be able to read in column names that include invalid characters, even if the characters are stripped off when read in.

Is there a way to force the `NameValidator` to not check for invalid characters, or to modify the characters it checks for? I am unable to modify numpy/lib/_iotools.py as I am not root and it would be bad to modify a shared installation.

Comment: Couldn't you extract the header by yourself and then skip it for pure data extraction by `genfromtxt`?

Comment: @JakobS. - I'm currently experimenting with that, reading in the header row and then using regex to find which names contain the invalid characters and replace them. However, this doesn't feel like a homogenous solution to me and I'm hoping that numpy has a provision to bypass the NameValidator or at least redefine the deletechars.

Comment: Hi, while I have given an answer based on my best guess of problem, it would probably help if you gave a simplified but full example of the csv file.

Answer (score 2):

You do not explicitly state that numpy.genfromtxt is a hard requirement, so let me suggest that you try [asciitable](http://cxc.harvard.edu/contrib/asciitable/).

This module has a way to replace certain entries before parsing: http://cxc.harvard.edu/contrib/asciitable/#replace-bad-or-missing-values

And you can also define your own readers based on the existing ones: http://cxc.harvard.edu/contrib/asciitable/#advanced-table-reading

The output of asciitable reader are numpy arrays, so you should be able to replace the functions you currently use more or less directly with asciitable.

Answer (score 1):

`NameValidator` will use its default set for `deletechars` if constructed with `deletechars=None`, but if you pass in a non-`None` set then it will use that.  And `np.genfromtext` takes a `deletechars` parameter which it passes to `NameValidator`.

So, you should be able to write

```
np.genfromtxt(..., deletechars=set())
```

for an empty set, or some subset of the default `set("""~!@#$%^&*()-=+~\|]}[{';: /?.>,<""")`:

```
deletechars = np.lib._iotools.NameValidator.defaultdeletechars - set("# ")
np.genfromtxt(..., deletechars=deletechars)
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, `genfromtxt` is often used in cases where some simpler solutions would do.

So, unless you have some troublesome datasets (missing entries, multiple unknown column types), you're better off coding a quick and dirty parser (ie, skip some rows, parse the header, read the rest and reorganize at the end).

Now, if you really need `genfromtxt`, @ecatmur pointed justly that the `deletechars` argument of `genfromtxt` is sent to `_iotools.NameValidator` to constructs the set of characters to delete. Using `deletechars=None` tells `NameValidator` to use a default set. A first thing to try is to just not use `deletechars=None`, but an empty `set` or `''`.

Note that no matter what, double quotes `"` and ending spaces will be deleted and similar names will be differentiated:

```
>>> fields = ["blah", "'blah'", "\"blah\"", "#blah", "blah "]
>>> np.lib._iotools.NameValidator(deletechars='').validate(fields)
... ('blah', "'blah'", 'blah_1', '#blah', 'blah_2')
```

The third and last entries would result in three columns named `blah`, so we have to rename them.

If this doesn't suit you, I'm afraid you're hitting a block: there's no current way to tell `genfromtxt` to accept a customized `NameValidator`. That could be a good idea, though, so you may want to raise the point on numpy's mailing list.

Comment: @xubuntix - I will check my installation to see if asciitable is available. Unfortunately in my work environment, the process of adding a new module is very difficult.
@ecatmur @Pierre GM - I have also tried `deletechars=set()` in `genfromtxt` but the NameValidator class simply performs a `set.extend("""~!@#$%^&*()-=+~\|]}[{';: /?.>,<""")` with whatever is passed in. As you can imagine, setting `deletechars=''` raises a ValueError due to no string.extend() method. Also, attempting to modify `np.lib._iotools` won't work because `genfromtxt` creates a new instance.
Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @user1580983 As a quick solution: make you own function with the code of `np.genfromtxt` and get rid of the `NameValidator`. That won't be portable but will keep you going. I would recommend to post about this issue on the numpy mailing list and eventually open a ticket.