# Numpy.genfromtxt deleting square brackets in dtype.names

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I'm trying to read in data from files using numpy.genfromtxt.  I set the names parameter to a comma-separated list of strings, such as

```
names = ['a', '[b]', 'c']
```

However, when the array is returned, the dtype.names value returns `('a', 'b', 'c')`

The `deletechars` parameter is either not set or forced to be `None`.  I've checked that creating a numpy.ndarray with a dtype that has a named column with square brackets preserves the square brackets, so it must be that genfromtxt is deleting the square brackets.  Is there a way to turn off this unexpected feature?

Note, this behavior also occurs if the `names` parameter is set to `True`.  I've tested this in numpy versions 1.6.1 and 1.9.9

Answer (score 2):

I've complained about this field name mangling behavior before on the [numpy issue tracker](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5686) and mailing list. It has also cropped up in [several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11840322/1461210) [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16020137/1461210) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29097917/1461210) on SO.

In fact, by default `np.genfromtxt` will mangle field names even if you specify them directly by passing a list of strings as the `names=` parameter:

```
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

s = '[5],name with spaces,(x-1)!\n1,2,3\n4,5,6'

x = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(s), delimiter=',', names=True)
print(repr(x))
# array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0)], 
#       dtype=[('5', '<f4'), ('name_with_spaces', '<f4'), ('x1\n1', '<f4')])

names = s.split(',')[:3]
x = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(s), delimiter=',', skip_header=1, names=names)
print(repr(x))
# array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0)], 
#       dtype=[('5', '<f4'), ('name_with_spaces', '<f4'), ('x1\n1', '<f4')])
```

This happens despite the fact that field names containing non-alphanumeric characters are perfectly legal:

```
x2 = np.empty(2, dtype=dtype)
x2[:] = [(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0)]
print(repr(x2))
# array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0)], 
#       dtype=[('[5]', '<f4'), ('name with spaces', '<f4'), ('(x-1)!\n1', '<f4')])
```

The logic of this behavior escapes me.

---

As you've seen, passing `None` as the `deletechars=` argument is not enough to prevent this from happening, since this argument gets initialized internally to a set of default characters within [`numpy._iotools.NameValidator`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/97c35365beda55c6dead8c50df785eb857f843f0/numpy/lib/_iotools.py#L303).

However, you *can* pass an empty sequence instead:

```
x = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(s), delimiter=',', names=True, deletechars='')
print(repr(x))
# array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0)], 
#       dtype=[('[5]', '<f8'), ('name_with_spaces', '<f8'), ('(x-1)!', '<f8')])
```

This could be an empty string, list, tuple etc. It doesn't matter as long as its length is zero.

Comment: Thanks, ali_m.  I saw this solution in a bug tracker [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2509).  @unutbu, was considering correcting after the fact, but the empty parameter is much easier.  Will test, then accept the answer.

Comment: Those characters may ok in a structured array dtype, but not as attribute names for a recarray.  I see that same sort of tension in `argparse` - do you give the user enough rope to hang themself?

Comment: @hpaulj Nope - they are also legal for recarrays (although of course you can't use the `.attribute`-style syntax to access them). Whether or not they *should* be legal is another question, but my point is that `np.genfromtxt` should not arbitrarily mess with legal field names.

Comment: `loadtxt` uses `dtype=np.dtype([('a','i'),('[b]','f'),('c','f')])` without change.

Comment: I just noticed that as well - that may have changed in the most recent release. My other objections still stand, though :-)

Answer (score 2):

In [String formatting issue (parantheses vs underline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538195/string-formatting-issue-parantheses-vs-underline)
I found that `dtype=None` is required in addition to the `deletechars` parameter:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32540939/901925

```
In [168]: np.genfromtxt([b'1,2,3'],names=['a','[b]','xcx'],delimiter=',',deletechars='',dtype=None)
Out[168]: 
array((1, 2, 3), 
      dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('[b]', '<i4'), ('xcx', '<i4')])
```

With the default `dtype` (float), `deletechars` is used, but the names pass through a second validator, `easy_dtype` which does not get this parameter.

```
In [170]: np.genfromtxt([b'1,2,3'],names=['a','[b]','xcx'],delimiter=',',deletechars='x')
Out[170]: 
array((1.0, 2.0, 3.0), 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4649

---

Field names can be changed after loading:

```
In [205]: data=np.genfromtxt([b'1 2 3 txt'],names=['a','b','c','d'],dtype=[int,float,int,'S4'])

In [206]: data.dtype.names
Out[206]: ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

In [207]: data.dtype.names=['a','[b]','*c*','d']

In [208]: data
Out[208]: 
array((1, 2.0, 3, 'txt'), 
      dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('[b]', '<f8'), ('*c*', '<i4'), ('d', 'S4')])
```

This works for names taken from the file itself:

```
In [212]: data=np.genfromtxt([b'a [b] *c* d','1 2 3 txt'],dtype=[int,float,int,'S4'],names=True)
```

Comment: indeed, without `dtype=None`, the answer given by @ali_m doesn't work.  unfortunately, i can't specify `dtype=None` because i don't want all of the data to be read in as strings and not automatically cast to something else by genfromtxt.  i'm instead left to write my own file reading routine.

Comment: Why not use simple field names during loading, and change them to something with funny characters afterwards?  See my edit.

Comment: While it is possible to modify the array's `dtype.names` after the fact, doing so still requires code modification, as I don't know _a priori_ which line in the input files contain the header information.  There are several different input file formats, and, in some cases, I use `genfromtxt` built-in features to determine which line contains the column names.  Since I now have to write code that reads in the files to determine the `names` parameter, I might as well just write the code to read in the data themselves, as well.