# numpy.genfromtxt removes colons from names/keys

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I use numpy's `np.genfromtxt(FileName,delimiter=",",names=True)` to import a csv file into a numpy array. Everything seems to work fine, except that my header has names with a colon (e.g. `Points:1`), but numpy sets the key for this data column without the colon (e.g. `Points1`).

Why is this happening and is there any way to prevent it?

### MWE

min.csv:

```
"Time", "Points:0", "Points:1"
0.0, 1.0, 2.0
3.0,4.0,5.0
```

script:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("min.csv",delimiter=",",names=True)
print data
print data.dtype
```

output:

```
[( 0.,  1.,  2.) ( 3.,  4.,  5.)]
[('Time', '<f8'), ('Points0', '<f8'), ('Points1', '<f8')]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `numpy` documentation under 'validating names':

> `deletechars` Gives a string combining all the characters that must be
>   deleted from the name. By default, invalid characters are
>   `~!@#$%^&*()-=+~\|]}[{';: /?.>,<` .

So all you need to do is to add your own `deletechars` value. In the example below I just copied the string from the documentation and removed the colon:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt(
    "min.csv",delimiter=",",names=True,
    deletechars="~!@#$%^&*()-=+~\|]}[{'; /?.>,<",
)
print data
print data.dtype
```

And the result looks like this:

```
[( 0.,  1.,  2.) ( 3.,  4.,  5.)]
[('Time', '<f8'), ('Points:0', '<f8'), ('Points:1', '<f8')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `deletechars` parameter to control what's removed from the names.  Normally the names are 'sanitized' so they would work as `recarray` names (i.e. as valid Python variable/attribute names).  In the past I found the `dtype=None` was also required to get this work (that may be corrected now).

[Numpy.genfromtxt deleting square brackets in dtype.names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234643/numpy-genfromtxt-deleting-square-brackets-in-dtype-names)

```
In [1137]: txt = b""""Time", "Points:0", "Points:1"
      ...: 0.0, 1.0, 2.0
      ...: 3.0,4.0,5.0"""
In [1141]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',names=True,deletechars='',dtype=None)
Out[1141]: 
array([( 0.,  1.,  2.), ( 3.,  4.,  5.)],
      dtype=[('Time', '<f8'), ('Points:0', '<f8'), ('Points:1', '<f8')])
```